# how to change css value

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tabs

I have a class in css file like this

```
#current a::after {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

I need to change backround color by clicking on checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element" ).click(function(){    

        $("#current a::after").css("background-color:", "red");     

    });
```

What is the right syntax of my code?

Comment: remove the `:` sign from `background-color`

Comment: it has to look either: `$("#current a::after").css({"background-color" : "red"});` or `$("#current a::after").css("background-color", "red");`

Answer (score 3):

According to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/3349272) manipulating CSS pseudo-elements with jquery is not possible.

But here's a solution to your issue...

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element" ).click(function(){   
        $("#current a").addClass("after");     
    });
});
```

(You could also use "toggleClass" depending on what you're trying to achive.)

CSS

```
#current a.after:after{
    background-color: red;
}
```

This is just a different solution to the same problem. By adding a class and a new CSS style you can achieve the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary `:` in your property.

The `css()` function in jQuery will take either 2 parameters *(property, value)* for a single change:

`$('div').css('background-color','#fff');`

or an object for multiple changes:

`$('div').css({'background-color':'#fff', 'color':'#000'});`